# ColdFusion : Symbolic links getting rewritten to actual location in template path

Tags: apache, coldfusion, symlink, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-11

I'm in the process of upgrading a large legacy ColdFusion application from ColdFusion-9 to ColdFusion-11.

Doing preliminary testing with the following directory structure

```
/dir1
     /dir2
           /symlink
                 |
                 |
/real_dir1       |
   /real_dir2    |
      /symlink <--
           test.cfm
```

I have noticed a difference in how the symlink in the path is handled by the different versions of ColdFusion. I am not sure if this due to configuration differences or rather the difference comes from Coldfusion itself. (Coldfusion 9 uses Jrun ... Coldfusion11 uses tomcat)

On ColdFusion 9 instance - getCurrentTemplatePath() returns  :: `/dir1/dir2/symlink/`

On ColdFusion 11 instance  - getCurrentTemplatePath() returns :: `/real_dir1/real_dir2/symlink/`

I use Apache as external web server  (configured  the same between the two and I do follow symlinks)

Looking at the mod_jk.log I can see (Coldfusion 11)_

```
   [debug] mod_jk.c (508): getRealPath(/dir1/dir2/symlink/test) = /dir1/dir2/symlink/test.cfm
```

but then responds to the request with the the absoulte path  /real_dir1/real_dir2/symlink

Has anyone encountered similar issues with symlinks on Coldfusion?

Comment: Did you ever work this out, I'm having the opposite problem going from CF11 -> CF2018 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65561344/coldfusion-2018-vs-11-centos-6-vs-7-handling-of-symlinks