# Coldfusion 2018 vs 11, Centos 6 vs 7, handling of symlinks

Tags: coldfusion, centos, symlink, cfml

I'm getting different outputs from `getCurrentTemplatePath` in CF2018 on Centos7 vs CF11 on Centos6

`/path/to/folder` contains a symlink `v1` which points to `/path/to/v1`

With an apache website using DocumentRoot `/path/to/folder`, then visiting `/v1` in a browser, the index.cfm dumps out `expandPath('.')` and `getCurrentTemplatePath()`

in CF11 on Centos6, I get:

- expandPath: /path/to/v1
- getCurrentTemplatePath: /path/to/v1/index.cfm

in CF2018 on Centos7, I get:

- expandPath: /path/to/v1
- getCurrentTemplatePath: /path/to/folder/v1/index.cfm

Can anyone explain why the `getCurrentTemplatePath` is different between the 2?

My issue is there is no `Applicaiton.cfc` in `/path/to/folder` but there is in `path/to/v1`

The index.cfm in CF11 will see the Application.cfc but CF2018 wont

Comment: Because there were changes between versions 11 and 2016, then from versions 2016 to 2018 and now changes between versions 2018 and 2021.You have to regression test all your upgrades and refactor as needed. You can't expect skipping a major version will not incur technical debt. It could also be related to version changes with Apache.

Comment: Yeah of course, and I'm looking at ways around it now, but I was hoping someone might know of a setting somewhere that would change how the path is traversed with symlinks, but I've pretty much given up hope of that now. Seems odd that expandPath has remained the same

Comment: right, well thanks to commandbox I've run the same very simple code in both CF11 and CF2018 on the Centos7 server and they give me the same result, so I guess this must be an issue with Centos 6 vs 7 then. I'll go on the Centos6 box and do the same test, to narrow it down further